# XCRF Token Axios / Nuxt plugin - 403 Forbidden

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I've been searching for solution since few hours and not able to find any. 
Doing post request via `axios` `nuxt` plugin is not working as expected:

**nuxt.config.js** file:

```
    axios: {
        debug: true,
        baseURL: `${process.env.API_PROTOCOL}://${process.env.API_HOST}${process.env.API_PORT ? `:${process.env.API_PORT}` : ''}${process.env.API_PREFIX}`,
    },
```

**axios plugin**:

```
export default function ({
    $axios, redirect, store,
}) {
    $axios.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $axios.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    $axios.onRequest((config) => {
        const configLocal = config;
        const { jwt } = store.state.authentication;

        if (jwt) {
            configLocal.headers.JWTAuthorization = `Bearer ${jwt}`;
        }

        if (config.method === 'post') {
            configLocal.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
            configLocal.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = store.state.authentication.crfToken;
        }
    });
}
```

And call **methods**:

```
authenticateUser({ commit }, { data }) {
    return this.app.$axios.$post('auth/login', data).then(({ token }) => {
        this.$cookies.set('jwt', token);
        commit('setAction', { key: 'jwt', value: token });
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
},
getCRFToken({ commit }) {
    return this.app.$axios.$get('auth/token').then(({ token }) => {
        this.$cookies.set('crf', token);
        commit('setAction', { key: 'crfToken', value: token });
    });
},
```

The `getCRFTToken` works like a charm by returning CSRF token:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/token
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

{"token":"92618f1e-0ed3-472b-b6a9-db2201a02d86"}
```

But whenever I do login...

[image]

It fails. Was digging in github - trying to set `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header in many places, but nope - still doesn't work. Anyone know the solution for this case ?

**Edit**
[image]

Comment: Could you share screenshots of the Console tab in your browser? It will most likely have a more helpful error message.

Comment: @JustinHoTuanDuong Look at the edit

Comment: The issue is then most likely with your back end. You will have to dig into the logs and check what are the params that you need to pass to be a valid request.

Answer (score 0):

In the config folder there is **shield.js** file which config is blocking your route.
Set enable in csrf to **false** in the file.
It will start woking then.